# Blur images using Java?

Tags: java, image

I want to blur a picture and then slowly to make it focus.

I want to do it with java, there is any open source that do this?

I found some open sources that blur the picture but none that do the reverse.

Comment: AFAIK, Sharpening is much harder than blurring. Blurring is not a reversible process you can only do a reasonably good job with sharpening.

Comment: Creating lots of progressively blurred pictures and then playing backwards is the way to go, I suspect

Comment: Check out the sample here https://github.com/madhur/blur-java

Answer (score 3):

Have a read about (or Google) **Convolution Filters** - it's basically a way of changing a pixels value based on the values of the pixels around it. So apart from blurring, you can also do things like image sharpening, line-finding etc.

Comment: @RazCohen Feel free to 'accept' my answer if it helped you and may help others in the future! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Java FX 2 has some methods to apply a blur effect - see for example [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/visual_effects/blur.htm). The example can be adapted to blur an image instead of text.

You can blur your image then progressively "unblur" it to make it look more focused.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little code for you:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Blur 
{
    
    static BufferedImage img;
    
    public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException
    {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("res/image.png"));
        
        JFrame f = new JFrame("blur");
        
        f.setSize(img.getWidth() * 2, img.getHeight());
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setIconImage(img);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
                g.drawImage(blur(10, 69), img.getWidth(), 0, null);
            }
        };
        f.add(panel);
        f.setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
    private static int clamp(int var, int min, int max)
    {
        if(var <= min) return min;
        else if(var >= max) return max;
        else return var;
    }
    
    public static BufferedImage blur(int range, int angle)
    {
        BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth() * 2, img.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = b.createGraphics();
        
        for(int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++)
            {
                
                //horizontal
                
                int red[] = new int[range * 2], green[] = new int[range * 2], blue[] = new int[range * 2];
                int pixels[] = new int[range * 2];
                
                for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
                {
                    pixels[i] = img.getRGB(clamp(x - clamp(range / 2, 0, range) + i, 0, img.getWidth() - 1), clamp(y - clamp(range / 2, 0, range) + (int)(i * Math.toRadians(angle)), 0, img.getHeight() - 1));
                    
                    red[i] = (pixels[i] >> 16) & 0xff;
                    green[i] = (pixels[i] >> 8) & 0xff;
                    blue[i] = (pixels[i]) & 0xff;
                }
                
                int red_t = 0, green_t = 0, blue_t = 0;
                
                for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
                {
                    red_t += red[i];
                    green_t += green[i];
                    blue_t += blue[i];
                }
                
                int r = red_t / (range * 2);
                int gr = green_t / (range * 2);
                int bl = blue_t / (range * 2);
                
                //System.out.println(r + ", " + gr + ", " + bl);
                
                g.setColor(new Color(r, gr, bl));
                g.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
                
            }
        }
        g.dispose();
        
        return b;
    }

}
```

As you have probably guessed, the most important part is the `public static BufferedImage blur(int range, int angle)` method.
Most of the code is just for displaying the image in the JFrame but if you just copy the method it should work as well. You need a reference to `img` tho, but you can just create that in a variable as I did. If you want to know more about how the code works, or if you have any questions just ask me.
this is a linear blur, the most common blur is a gaussian blur. If you want that, you just have to make the `pixels`, `red`, `green` and `blue` variable a 2-dimensional array.
The end result of only this code should look like this:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc1UD.png)